# How to connect CircleCI and AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, circleci, multi-factor-authentication

I'm new to CircleCI, and trying to connect CircleCI - terraform - AWS.

For security reasons, I enforced MFA for aws cli. In other words, I'm using temporal 24-hour lasting:

- aws_access_key_id
- aws_secret_access_key
- aws_session_token.

It's quite tricky to apply circleCI in this situation.

What should I do? 
Should I have to change the above mentioned AWS credentials before every commit?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/.../edit) your question and include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Without code, your question is hard to understand. 

Also make sure to use [code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) for code and preformatted text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your only option is to create an access key with MFA disabled and use it for ciecleci.

There is no way around this as MFA code should be entered manually.

Also you should configure the AWS credentials as environment variable to your circleci project.

Remember, MFA is for people, not for machines

Comment: Oh, MFA is not for machines..!! Thanks a lot!